# Заполнить коллекцию из JSON

Tags: android, json

Есть скрипт, который возвращает json файл типа

```
{
  "audios": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "folder": "site_music/Папка1",
      "audio": "Аудио1.mp3",
      "url": "https://site.ru/site_music/Папка1/Аудио1.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "folder": "site_music/Папка1",
      "audio": "Аудио2.mp3",
      "url": "https://site.ru/site_music/Папка1/Аудио2.mp3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Также есть класс **Audio** - , который характеризует объект аудио

```
public class Audio {

    private int id;
    private String folder;
    private String audio;
    private String url;

    public Audio(int id, String folder, String audio, String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.folder = folder;
        this.audio = audio;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFolder() {
        return folder;
    }

    public void setFolder(String folder) {
        this.folder = folder;
    }

    public String getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    public void setAudio(String audio) {
        this.audio = audio;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Как заполнить коллекцию объектами типа Audio, которые возвращает json?

Comment: Ответы по вашей ссылке полезные, но там описано как работать с json, который записан в String. У меня json, а точнее скрипт php, который возвращает json лежит на хостинге. Мне бы не хотелось копировать данные из этого json в String, а потом из String парсить в массив или коллекцию. Есть ли какой-то нормальный способ, который позволяет заполнить коллекцию, который имеет пользовательский тип данными из json, который лежит на хостинге?

Comment: @Kolhoznik `new Gson().toJson(String)`

Answer (score 0):

С помощью GSON легко делается:

1) `Type type = new TypeToken<List<Audio>>() {}.getType();`

2) `List<Audio> yourList = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, type);`

PS Главное, чтобы имена совпадали с объектами json, иначе нужно использовать аннотацию `@SerializedName`

Пример:

`public class Audio {
    @SerializedName("id") //в скробках имя JSON-елемента
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("folder")
    private String folder;
    @SerializedName("audio")
    private String audio;
    @SerializedName("url") 
    private String url;
}`

Comment: А если json в сети, то как быть? Из json импортировать в строку и строку подсунуть в gson?

Comment: Я так понял изначально проблема, что делать со строкой, разве нет?

Comment: Можно вообще с помощью Simple Json сделать: `JSONArray array = new JSONArray(String);`

Comment: Не совсем.. если в String есть данные я могу его парсить через gson. Проблема в том что я не знаю как быть если сам file.json лежит в сети

Comment: Надо его загрузить, выполнить скрипт на сервере и чтобы на выходе в ответе была json-строка

Comment: Загрузить в строку и со строкой работать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88742/discussion-between-georgehardcore-and-kolhoznik).